# Cannot install Ubuntu (14/16/17) on i7-7820x and Gigabyte x299-UD4

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my new machine. The specs are:

-Gigabyte x299-UD4 (rev. F2)

-i7-7820x

-32gb 2400mhz-DDR4 kingston CL15

-960 M2 ssd samsung

These errors appear while i try to boot up the installer:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jzd3.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5GzU.jpg)

I should return this motherboard right? Windows setup runs fine. It is really strange i cannot even boot the ubuntu setup. I have searched everywhere and i can't find a reference for this. I'm really disappointed with Gigabyte. I bought this machine exclusively for linux usage and i find it hard that nobody on the MB development team boot up linux once.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I'm experienceing exactly the same - https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=251942

Comment: This question is not reproducible (off topic) because the OP returned the hardware.

Comment: I had the same configuration but different errors. Try to use the latest versions of Ubuntu and BIOS. Then use acpi=off kernel option to boot installer.

Comment: It's not a duplicate at all.

Comment: Unbelievable, Gigabyte X299-UD4 has another issue with DRAM even in Windows 10. System hangs, DRAM error LED lights on. It happened after 1 week of use. Will be returned definitely!

Comment: Just setup a system on a MSI X229 SLI PLUS and ran into this issue trying to install ubuntu gnome 16.04.  Disabled Turbostep in the bios and was able to boot and install.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to return the hardware. I want nothing to do x299.

Through my investigation i concluded that is something to do with hyperthreading.You can try to disable it. I think there are only some steppings affected by this. Return the CPU+MB combo

https://hothardware.com/news/intel-hyperthreading-bug-fixed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same processor, on a Gigabyte Aorus x299 Gaming 3. The issue seems to affect lower-end Gigabyte x299 motherboards.

I managed to install using the boot kernel parameter "acpi=off", but had to keep the parameter in the installed bootloader too - which has the downside of disabling hyperthreading. The system was not fully stable, with occasional hangs.

Ended up replacing the motherboard with an Asus x299 Prime-A, which worked without any issues. Other mobos for which I found hints of good compatibility:

Gigabyte Aorus Gaming 9: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WpKPw56ABQU

MSI SLI Plus: http://www.phoronix.com/vr.php?view=24854

Comment: Can you please confirm that your system is stable now? What CPU and GPU do you use?

Comment: Yes, my system has been stable since. CPU: i7-7820X, GPU: Aorus 1080 Ti.

Comment: And are you sure that you don't use "acpi=off" anymore? I saw on the Internet that all users of X299 chipset have the same issue. Just want to figure out if I should return it and replace as well...

Comment: I don't need to use the flag, as I have had no issues since I switched to the Asus x299 board. Not all x299 boards are affected, see the links in my answer, those boards were tested with many distros and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! What do you think about ASUS TUF X299 Mark 2?

Comment: I don't know about its compatibility so I recommend you look for boards you've found some proof they work with Linux. These issues will probably be solved sooner or later for all boards, but there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Booting from a 17.04 server usb key with "acpi=off intel_pstate=disable" appended to grub command worked. Exact same specs as you.

Note: "acpi=off" will disable hyperthreading.

Comment: Did this work for anyone?

Comment: Does kernel update help to enable hyperthreading?

Comment: Yes, it does. But it works only few minutes in both cases. And after "boot repair" tool it works only few seconds!!! By the way, why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue specifically is: "Machine check - Processor context corrupt"

Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819681/machine-check-processor-context-corrupt).

Comment: I was able to install and boot Ubuntu. The system was super unstable and crashed a LOT

Comment: Me too! Did you find a solution?